# Thread to add items in Treeview - pygtk

Tags: python, multithreading, pygtk

I am trying to develop a downloader app in pygtk
So when a user adds a url following actions happen

> - addUrl()

which calls

> > - validateUrl()
> > - getUrldetails()

So it took a little while to add the url to the list because of `urllib.urlopen` delay
so i tried to implement threads. I added the following code to main window

`thread.start_new_thread(addUrl, (self,url, ))`
I passed a reference to the main window so that i can access the list from thread
but nothing seems to happen

Comment: What exactly is your question? What list?

Comment: I think that you check this thread first http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/python-multithreading-for-dummies.
Hope this helps you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think that you check this thread first [How to use threading in Python?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2846653/python-multithreading-for-dummies).
**for example:**
    import Queue
    import threading
    import urllib2

```
# called by each thread
def get_url(q, url):
    q.put(urllib2.urlopen(url).read())

theurls = '''http://google.com http://yahoo.com'''.split()

q = Queue.Queue()

for u in theurls:
    t = threading.Thread(target=get_url, args = (q,u))
    t.daemon = True
    t.start()

s = q.get()
print s
```

Hope this helps you.